# How do I know which partition to consume in Kafka?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, messagebroker

I have one topic with 3 partitions in Kafka broker
1 partitions have message and 2 partitions are empty, how do I know which partition to consume in one call?

First I assign a TopicPartition with partition equals to `kafka.PartitionAny`, but this value keeps returning -1

So I have to manually use a counter, and when I successfully consume from one partition but with null message, then `count++` and start with next one, until I find the message

```golang
for{

    partitions = append(partitions, kafka.TopicPartition{
        Topic:     &topic,
        Partition: partition,
        Offset:    offSet,
        Error:     err,
    })


    err = c.Assign(partitions)
    if err != nil {
         return err
    }

    // retrieve message
    ev, err := c.Poll(-1)
    if err != nil {
         return err
    }

    // if no message, check the next partition
    if ev == nil{
         partition++
    }else{
         break
    }

}
```

The first two round does not return any message, but it has to wait for the third round to return, is there any way it can automatically detect which partition is stored with un-consumed message?

If there is no other way, can Kafka do the round-robin routing for me? or I have to record the counter myself

Thanks! :)

Comment: You can use `Subscribe()` instead of `Assign()` if you just want to consume all the message without knowing which partition the message will be stored.

Comment: @max23_Thanks for the reply! but if I use Subscribe(), how do I commit the offset manually?

Comment: Do you need to manually handle the offset yourself? There is a Consumer config called `enable.auto.commit` that is set to true by default which will periodically commit the offset in the background.

Comment: @max23_ yes, I need to handle the offset myself :(
it seems that the subscribe method cannot specify which offset to consume

Comment: Oh, I see there is a rebalance callback when you use the subscribe method. It will either return you AssignedPartitions or RevokedPartitions event that has a list of `TopicPartition`. Probably can give it a try like handling AssignedPartitions event.

Comment: The way of committing has nothing to do weither you use subscribe() or assign(). You can commit manually while doing subscribe() ( just depends on ```enable.auto.commit```)

Comment: Any specific library you are using. In my case I use librdkafka go library.
After consuming certain number of messages I commit the offset via `Commit` method of kafka consumer.

Comment: @RajanChauhan I'm using confluentinc kafka go library to do the commit, but they are pretty much the same

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use subscribe() method and then call poll().
If there are available records, you'll get a Records answer containing one or multiple records ( associated with different partitions).

After processing a record, you can then commit manually ( if you use `enable.auto.commit = false`) using the medata contained in the record ( topic, partitions, offset, etc..).

Yannick

Comment: But I can still specifying which offset to consume when using `subscribe` right? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can still use kafkaConsumer.seek() to specify which offset you're aiming